# symfony 4.0 form_errors() doesn't work

Tags: php, forms, validation, symfony4

I'm using Symfony 4.0 framework I have a problem. I created form it works without a problem but I can't see form_errors() text, it's not working.

Where am I doing wrong in this code?

**My controller:**

```
$user = new Users();

$form = $this->createFormBuilder($user)
    ->add('firstName', TextType::class, array('label'=> 'Name','error_bubbling' => false))
    ->add('lastName',TextType::class, array('label'=> 'Lastname','error_bubbling' => false))
    ->add('Email', EmailType::class, array('label' => 'Email','error_bubbling' => false))
    ->add('Password', RepeatedType::class, array(
        'type' => PasswordType::class,
        'error_bubbling' => false,
        'invalid_message' => 'The password fields must match.',
        'options' => array('attr' => array('class' => 'password-field')),
        'first_options'  => array('label' => 'Password','error_bubbling' => true),
        'second_options' => array('label' => 'Repeat Password'),
    ))
    ->add('Save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Register'))
    ->getForm();

$data['form'] = $form->createView();

$form->handleRequest($request);

$errors = $validator->validate($user);

if($errors->count() > 0){
    $data['errors'] = $errors;
    return $this->output('user/register',$data);
}
```

I created form cannot get twig render. Can't see errors text

**..html.twig:**

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
{{ form_row(form) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

Comment: did it show  errors in your page or on log file ?

Comment: no have errors my page and logs
working validation and i see form validation calls in symfony _profiler but i cant see errors text

form is working and
creating input label .. but only doesnt work {{ form_errors() }]

Comment: can you show your users entity ?

Comment: use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UserRepository")
 */
class Users implements UserInterface, \Serializable
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Email()
     */
    protected $email;

Comment: get too long error for text this comment field sorry

Comment: i see the problem